# EF Code First, IoC and DbConnection

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, inversion-of-control, entity-framework-5

I'm using Entity Framework Code First. I want to be able to inject a `System.Data.Common.DbConnection` object when instantiating the context that derives from `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`. This is so that I can pass different types of connections depending on what environment the code is running in, i.e. use `System.Data.SqlClient` (SQL Server) in development, `System.Data.SQLite` when unit testing and something else in production. The pertinent parts of `Context` looks like this:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context(DbConnection dbConnection)
        : base(dbConnection, true)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Context, Configuration>());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; }
}
```

That gives me the following error: `The target context 'Services.Persistence.Context' is not constructible. Add a default constructor or provide an implementation of IDbContextFactory.` I think this happens during model initialization when Entity Framework apparently feels it needs to new up it's own `Context`, independent of the IoC pattern I'm trying to achieve. The lack of a default constructor is by design. The `IDbContextFactory` interface is just as useless - it has to have a default constructor too.

Is Entity Framework Code First completely wedded to the idea of setting up it's config by reading a connectionstring from a config file (or alternatively getting the connectionstring passed directly) or can one work around this?

*UPDATE*, here's the Windsor config:

```
container.Register(Component
    .For<DbConnection>()
    .UsingFactoryMethod(() =>
        new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\\v11.0;Database=ThatProject;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"))
    .LifeStyle.Transient);

container.Register(Component
    .For<Context>()
    .UsingFactoryMethod(k => new Context(k.Resolve<DbConnection>()))
    .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);

container.Register(Component
    .For<IRepository>()
    .UsingFactoryMethod(k => new Repository(k.Resolve<Context>()))
    .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
```

Comment: Which IoC container are you using?  And what's it's configuration for this type?

Comment: Windsor, the `Context` should prerably be PerWebRequest.

Comment: I meant, what is the actual configuration you are using?  How are you configuring the DbConnection to be passed in?

Comment: @MystereMan I've added the Windsor config to the question text.

Comment: Windsor is not my container of choice, but the way you're configuring things there just doesn't look right to me.  using service resolution is typically bad practice, and just newing things up doesn't seem like the right solution either.

Comment: @friism what is the problem with storing the connection info in the config file? It keeps everything else simpler, as you don't have to reinvent DB providers.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon It's kinda impractical for unit testing.

Comment: @friism I have to disagree; I use a separate `.config` file for my test project and never had an issue. I use Windsor too. What do you think makes it impractical?

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon I need the connection string passed in, so a config file will not work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure your issue is nothing to do with EF but I'm not really a user of Windsor so i cant tell you for sure what your config issue is. What I have done is to reproduce a similar configuration with ninject which works exactly as you would expect, see below:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Bind<DbConnection>().ToMethod((ctx) =>{return new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\\v11.0;Database=ThatProject;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");});
            kernel.Bind<Context>().ToSelf();//not really needed
            kernel.Bind<TestRepository>().ToSelf();//not really needed
            kernel.Get<TestRepository>();
        }
    }
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public Context(DbConnection dbConnection)
            : base(dbConnection, true){}

        public DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; }
    }
    public class TestRepository
    {
        public TestRepository(Context c)
        {
            c.Tests.Add(new Test());
            c.SaveChanges();

            var all = c.Tests;
        }
    }
    public class Test
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

This means that EF isn't trying to do any funkiness with context creation (as a non-empty constructor works fine for me).

From your Windsor config I would expect you need to do something like the following however im not too sure of the exact syntax:

```
container.Register(Component
    .For<DbConnection>()
    .UsingFactoryMethod(() =>
        new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\\v11.0;Database=ThatProject;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"))
    .LifeStyle.Transient);

container.Register(Component
    .For<Context>()
    .ImplementedBySelf()//this probably isn't the correct syntax
    .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);//per request is good, i have some details around why this is good practice if you are interested

container.Register(Component
    .For<IRepository>()
    .ImplementedBy<ConcreteRepository>()//you arent really calling a method and creating the object yourself you are letting Windsor create the object and sort out the dependancy tree
    .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
```

Comment: It turns out the problem only crops up when automatic migrations are enabled, I've added this to the code sample.